# Laravel Excel Import "model" function not getting called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel, import-csv

I have followed the steps like

`artisan make:import ProductImport --model=Products`

Now in my controller I have called the import:

```
Log::debug('Invoking product import for: cron/' . $filename);

Excel::import(new ProductImport,'cron/'.$filename,'public');

Log::debug('After product import');
```

In the productImport Script, I put:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
  Log::channel('cron')->info('foo bar productimport');
  Log::debug('app import product import');
```

And I do not see that model is invoking any how.

Now I tried some debug, I tried messing with file location and it throws exception. So file location is correct.

Can someone help me to figure out what am I missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the whole `ProductImport` class?

Comment: Hi @ChinLeung sure, added here, https://pastebin.com/g3Xtha0H

Comment: Just to make sure, you see the log `Invoking...` and `After product import`?

Comment: Yes, https://ibb.co/nn7GFkw

Comment: Hmm I see that you class is implementing `ShouldQueue`. So it would probably be executed later and therefore show up in the log only when the task is ran in the queue. You can try to remove that interface to see if it works properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I remove it, I can see its working straight way. So it seems main problem is my redis setup? Or I need some further tweaking to get queue work :-/

Comment: Yes exactly, it's either your queue driver not working properly or the task is ran later so you will find it in the log at some other time.

Comment: I have checked the log, what I wrote specifically for each product import and there is nothing for the last 7 days. So definitely it never ran. So last thing to check the Redis backend setup. 
Any suggestion what to check about the queue, since I didn't setup that before.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the documentation?